# How do I get the value of a record from model to another model in Odoo 8?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

For example I want to get the value of tax to multiply with a price value like:

```
class tax(models.Model):
   _name = 'tax'
   tax = fields.Float('tax')




class daily_transaction(models.Model):
   _name = "daily.transaction"
   total = fields.Float('total')
   price = fields.Float(compute ='adding')

   @api.multi
   def adding(self):

      ids =[1,2,3]
      tax = self.env['tax'].browse(ids)
      for record in self:

             record.total = record.price * float(tax.tax(1))
```

I get the Error ValueError

```
Expected singleton: tax(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do that for me is to make a relation between these two model and then just take the value like you are doing. There are another options too but this is better way for me.